# Mouse Stutter for USB Mouse in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mouse, 20.04, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am running `Ubuntu 20.04` in `VMWareWorkstation 15.1.0 build-13591040`, which runs on `Windows 10`, and am accessing Windows desktop through RDP. I have been doing this just fine since 20.04 was released. Over the past week, many updates have been available, and I've been letting them install, however, I have not rebooted after these. Sometime this past morning, our IT department "did me the favor". Now, when I run the VM, the mouse is losing track of its position and looks like it's shaking 1-2" back and forth as I move it. When I minimize my VM and use the mouse on my remote windows desktop, it's just fine -- So the problem is very much isolated to use within the Ubuntu VM. I popped open mouse settings, but there is only speed control. I have restarted the VM multiple times. Just moving the mouse onto the VMWare toolbar settles the mouse. For about 30s, the problem went away, but has since continued all day. What, if anything might I try to rectify this?

Thanks!

(The VM is updated to the latest from apt-get update/upgrade) as of this post.

Comment: Issue is also present at the login screen

Comment: Returned to a known good snapshot over 1mo old, and still having the issue -- maybe VMWare issue caused by latest windows update :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this issue is indeed a MS problem, and is fixed by modifying the following, on the windows machine hosting VMWare:

```
run: GPEDIT.msc


navigate: Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates >Windows Components > Remote Desktop Service > Remote Desktop Session Host >Remote Session Environment

modify: "Use WDDM graphics display driver for Remote Desktop Connections"
* value: DISABLED
```

Reboot the VMWare host machine.

Here's a more lengthy explanation: https://borncity.com/win/2019/10/30/windows-10-v1903-mouse-stutter-with-rdp-sessions/